# How do I determine why my Windows 10 bandwidth is so much lower than my Macbook Pro?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bandwidth

I'm using a Windows 10 machine (Dell Precision 5560 PC) and am noticing that my bandwidth (at least measured by speedtest.net) is 4 to 5 times lower than my MacBook Pro 2017, both on the same network, physically sitting next to each other.  When I look at my Windows 10 task manager, I can see only a couple of apps eating up a tiny amount of bandwidth

[image]

but this doesn't account for the vast difference between my two systems (total Mbps for Windows 10 is around 20Mbps and on Mac it is closer to 90Mbps).

When I try and analyze my data usage using Settings -> Network & Internet, the "Data Usage" button is grayed out.

[image]

Comment: Data Usage isn’t for WiFi it’s for 3G/4G/5G connection. You have to use third-party tools to accomplish that task on a WiFi 5/6/6e network. Task Manager is absolutely NOT the correct tool to diagnose network performance issues, it doesn’t provide enough details, to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool such as Nirsoft's [WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html), you can see *how* the PC is connected. For example, there may be multiple WiFi outputs from the router, and if the PC is connecting to a lower speed 802.1 standard, such as that using the 2.4 GHz band, or connecting to a channel that's lower power, it might be restricting throughput. One useful feature of *WifiInfoView* is that right-clicking on a connection allows you to connect immediately, to test if that's faster in SpeedTest.net, and *to create a desktop shortcut to that profile*, so that you can choose a higher-speed connection by double-clicking the link.

[image: WiFi Info View]

Comment: I'm not quite following.  I downloaded and installed this tool.  I can see all the LANs, including the one I'm connected to (a 5 GHz network).  Not sure how this helps me figure out why my PC's bandwidth is so much lower than my Mac's.  You think it's the channel I'm connected to?

Comment: It could be that the 5 GHz signal does not penetrate as well as the lower band; try changing band https://wccftech.com/how-to/how-to-change-between-2-4ghz-and-5ghz-wifi-bands-on-windows-10/ and/or 802.1 protocol, https://www.fairmontstate.edu/it/sites/default/files/Windows%2010%20Wifi%20Turorial.pdf

Comment: Interesting thought -- I tried connecting to my 2.4 GHz network but the bandwidth was even lower, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As it happened, there was a Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility client on my system, which I was not using.  Selecting my network and connecting to the Internet through there allowed speeds to return to expected levels.